# Using Django Check Framework to detect admin unknown fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

so imagine I have a `models.py`

```py
class User(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and I used to have a `last_name = models.CharField` that I have removed.

in `admin.py`

```py
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(models.Model):
   fields = ("name", "last_name")
```

When navigating in the admin, I obviously get a `FieldError: Unknown field(s) (last_name) specified for User`.

This error is not picked up by `./manage.py check`, which makes me sad. How do I set up the [Check Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/topics/checks/) so that it can detect such errors?

Comment: Wouldn't that be more a topic for [unit tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/)? Because you would need to call all functions reachable from any URL or management command to compile and run them, and then check if they access a non-existing property on any model.

Comment: Well you could write a test for each model to check those, but I'd like a more generic approach